# Devise authentication for every page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Every page on my site requires user authentication (user has to be logged in in order to access it). I found this in Devise documentation but it doesn't seems to work for me...

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-authentication-for-all-pages

I have copiy-pasted this:

```
 authenticated :user do
   root :to => 'home#index'
 end
 root :to => redirect('/users/sign_in')
```

How can I achieve this very natural feature?

Comment: Can you explain more which part does not work for you? Does it not redirect to the login page? Have you restarted your server for changes to the routes take affect?

Comment: It does not redirect me to login page. I can access every page without being logged in. Yes, I have tried restarting the server.

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers you need to use before_filter for that

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did:

In `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`, add a line as follow:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
    # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    before_action :authenticate_user!

    # ...
end
```

This will force `authenticate_user!` to run before any action.

If you have some actions/controllers that don't require authentication, you can add the following line to their controller file:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
    prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication

    # ...
end
```

The `require_no_authentication` function also takes an optional parameter, an array named `only`, that contains a list of the actions that do not require authentication.

n.b. I know this is advanced necromancy, but the question was unanswered, and I spent quite a bit of time chasing the correct answer.

Comment: I think the require_no_authentication function is only available in controllers that inherit from the devise so this doesnt work for me from other controllers